# regex to extract array from a remote page

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I'm doing some scraping and need to read data from a remote page. That page contains a  tag containing the array. What would be the best way to read this array into my script?

I've experimented with getting the page via jQuery. The following works, but I'm trained to consider eval() to be unsafe. I'm also experimenting with regex to isolate the array to then JSON.parse(), but not successful yet. So far, this is running in the browser.

code

```
$.ajax({
     url: url,
     success: doSuccess
});

 function doSuccess(data) {
      var script = $("script", data)[0]
      eval(script.text)

      console.log(images);
}
```

HTML excerpt

```
<script>
var images = [

    {
        id: 'xxx',
        title: '25th anniversary image',
        width: 919,
        height: 683,
        src: 'https://cdn.xxx.org/images/thumb/image.jpg',
    },

    {
        id: 'yyy',
        title: '26th anniversary image',
        width: 919,
        height: 683,
        src: 'https://cdn.xxx.org/images/thumb/image.jpg',
    },

];
</script>
```

Comment: why would you need to harvest anything from HTML elements at all? The script element  you're showing loads the var `images` into global scope, so just directly reference `images` in the same page and done: plain JS data at your code's finger tips. No parsing required. And yes: never use `eval`. or `new Function`/`setInterval`/`setTimeout` with plain text script code.

Comment: You won't be able to use `JSON.parse` because that is not JSON.

Comment: @str good point. I'd need to clean that up as well.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The <script> is just one element in a whole page w/ other data & UI. If you'd assumed that, I'm not clear on what you're suggesting.

Comment: Other way around: I assume you're asking about JS code in script tags that's already live on the page because _that's what you're showing_. Based on what you're showing, there is nothing to parse: the JS variable is already available in global scope, we're done. If there is more at play, please update your post with those details, as per the official Stackoverflow guidelines on [asking a good question](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Frontend or node? Node can eval safely with vm and you can probably browserify it but I don't have any info on that..

Comment: This is currently running in the browser (updated OP)

Comment: should `$("script", data)[0]` not be `$("script", dom)[0]`

Comment: @NickSlash That was a line I forgot to remove